# What is a Hellblazer?

Tags: comics, vertigo-comics, hellblazer

In the comic series *John Constantine, Hellblazer*, what exactly is a Hellblazer?

I've read the first 3 volumes (*Original Sins*, *The Devil You Know* and *The Fear Machine*) so I'm familiar with [John](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Constantine) and what he does - magician and occults.

However, I'm not entirely sure what the title "Hellblazer" refers to. The wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellblazer) doesn't seem to say.

Comment: I've often wondered this question myself!

Comment: The name has confused me too. Clearly he's wearing a trenchcoat

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that it's so much of *what* a Hellblazer is, but *who*.

From the [Hellblazer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellblazer) entry you linked:

> Hellblazer (also known as John Constantine, Hellblazer)

And the [John Constantine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Constantine) entry

> Also known as the Hellblazer, Constantine is a working-class magician, occult detective, and con man stationed in London. He is known for his endless cynicism, scathing wit, ruthless cunning, and constant chain smoking.

So, I think it's most appropriate to consider "Hellblazer" as his alternate name, the same as any more common hero.

Comment: The first one "Hellblazer (also known as John Constantine, Hellblazer)" I believe is referencing the title of the comic book as opposed to John himself. The cite for the Constantine entry lists "Stations of the Cross" (Hellblazer 194-200) do you know what happened in that story?

Comment: Right, but I don't think there's a difference. It's the same as titling it "Wolverine". I've only read a few issues. Unfortunately, not those ones.

Comment: It should be noted that the series was originally going to be called the similarly-named 'Hellraiser' before the recent Clive Barker movies were taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

I forget the source (maybe the letter column of an early issue?) but it seemed like a description, not a title, and they actually wanted to call him a Hellraiser. But the movie series would have been a confusion so they went with a similar word. It is not a thing, just a description of him and a title for the book.

Comment: Mention of this theory at http://www.insanerantings.com/hell/faq/index.html#mq2 but with no citations.